# Swagger res change status

Tags: node.js, api, swagger

I couldn't change the response status when an error has occur i tried like `res.status(404).send(err);` but it's not working. It doesn't change the response status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be working.  Status codes are kept in the statusCode part of your res object.

```
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
 res.status(400).send(err)
 console.log(res.statusCode)
})
```

Comment: It gives this error `TypeError: res.status is not a function`

Comment: Are you using express or vanilla node for your server?
If you're using just plain node or an early version of express, you can set the statusCode like this:  

res.statusCode = 404;

Comment: Yes that worked i used connect earlier and swifted it to express now.

Answer (score 0):

`res.status(400).send(err)` works for express on node
And for connect use `res.statusCode = 400`

Answer (score 0):

In swagger you'll need to use `utils.writeJson`
 and indicate the status code as third argument :

```
utils.writeJson(res, {"error":true, "message": "unauthorized access"} ,401);
```